# jQuery + PHP is sending duplicate blank emails

Tags: php, jquery, forms, email

Trying to set up a contact form. Form submits email and optionally CCs sender. If javascript is enabled, the form submits to contact-ajax.php (to replace the form with a thanks message), otherwise it submits to contact.php (to redirect to a thanks page). The fallback form works fine, but every time the ajax form fires it also sends a completely blank email (to both sender and recipient, if CC option is checked). I can't figure out why this is occurring. Any insight would be appreciated.

Form HTML:

```
<form method="post" id="email_form" name="email_form" action="contact.php">
    <label for="name">Name:</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="John Doe" /><br />
    <label for="email">Email Address:</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="johndoe@gmail.com" /><br />
    <label for="subject">Subject </label></td><br />
    <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" /><br />
    <label for="message">Message:</label></td><br />
    <textarea cols="35" rows="5" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="cc" id="cc" checked value="Yes" /><label for="cc"> Send yourself a copy of this message</label><br />
    <input class="submit pulldown button" name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="Send Message" />
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#email_form #submit').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajaxSetup ({
        cache: false
        });
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'contact-ajax.php',
        data: $("#email_form").serializeArray(),
        success: function(msg) {
            if(msg=='Mail sent') {
                alert(msg);
                }
            else {
                alert('Error sending mail. Please try again.');
                }
            },
        error: function(ob,errStr) {
            alert('Error sending mail. Please try again.');
            }
        });
    return false;
    });
});
```

PHP form called by script (contact-ajax.php):

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
    $email_subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $today = date('r');
    $email_from = "address@domain.tld";
    $to = "address@domain.tld";
    $email_body = "On $today $name wrote:\n"."$message";
    $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
    if (isset($_POST['cc'])) {
        $headers .= "CC: $visitor_email \r\n";
        }
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/". phpversion();
    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
        die('Mail sent');
        }
    else {
        die('Error: Mail failed');
        }
    }
?>
```

The non-Ajax php script (contact.php) is identical, except that it ends with `header('Location: thanks_page.html');` instead of the last `if` statement.

Blank emails contain no subject or message body, but From, Reply-To, and CC fields are all filled in exactly as they are in the correct (non-empty) message. I've been trying to figure out the problem for a few days now but can't seem to track it down.

Comment: have you checked if your post data contains anything once the javascript submits? if not then change your $("#email_form").serializeArray() to data: $("#email_form").serialize()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mail function send mail.. you write mail() 2 times.. Enought to check return value in if

```
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) { ......
```

use only this way:

```
if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) { //mail sent 
} else { 
//mail not sent 
}
```

**UPDATE**
use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer) easy to use and i think better than simple php mail function.

Comment: Ha! How did I miss that? The first line is directly from my contact.php. I had been using another ajax script as an example template, I think I must have forgotten to modify the mail function in the process. Working now! Thanks - the obvious answers are always the ones you miss when staring at the code!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is it:

```
if (isset($_POST['cc'])) {
    $headers .= "CC: $visitor_email \r\n";
}
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/". phpversion();
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers); <-- Sends FIRST email
if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) { <-- Sends ANOTHER email
    die('Mail sent');
    }
else {
    die('Error: Mail failed');
    }
}
```

Maybe try:

```
$retVal = mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
if($retVal) {
```

Thanx,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

Bence has a valid point you called the mail function twice...

I am not so sure why some info are blank but can you do this in PHP ? :

```
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
if (isset($_POST['cc'])) {
    $headers .= "CC: $visitor_email \r\n";
    }
```

I always do my concatenation like this instead :

```
$headers = "From: ".$email_from." \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$visitor_email." \r\n";
if (isset($_POST['cc'])) {
    $headers .= "CC: ".$visitor_email." \r\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Except for all the answers covering why you get two mails, there's a fairly obvious reason to why the second mail is empty:

```
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers))
```

In the if-statement you have `$subject` and `$body` instead of `$email_subject` and `$email_body`.